# Show that $A + I_n$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that $A$ is diagonalizable, how to show that $A + I_n$ is also diagonalizable?

All I know is that $A = PDP^{-1}$

I got to $A + I_n = PDP^{-1} +I_n$ but I am not sure how to prove that it's diagonalizable.

Another idea I had was $I_n = A^{-1}A = (PD^{-1}P^{-1})(PDP^{-1}) = PD^{-1}I_nDP^{-1}$ but I don't think this is right.

Thank you.

Comment: If there is an invertible $P$ and a diagonal $D$ for which $A = PDP^{-1}$. then $A + I = PDP^{-1} + I = PDP^{-1}  + PP^{-1} = P(D + I)P^{-1}$ and $D+I$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506989/let-a-be-an-n-×-n-real-diagonalizable-matrix-show-that-a-αin-is-also-real-dia/1507001#1507001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $I_n=PI_nP^{-1}$

Hope it helps!

Also, your answer was a good try, but it is not correct since $A$ is not necessarly invertible ($0$ could be an eigenvalue)

Comment: I understand about how D is not necessarily invertible but I am slightly confused why $I_n=PI_{n}P^{-1}$. Do you mind explaining where did it come from?

Comment: $PI_nP^{-1}=PP^{-1}=I_n$.

Comment: @mmei I kindly suggest revisiting the definition of a matrix inverse and the identity matrix. I also suggest picking your favorite matrix $A$ and multipying it by $I$.